# group a list of lists and count occurence of the second element for a unique first element

Tags: python, list, machine-learning, group-by, decision-tree

I was trying to find the best variable to split a decision tree on and it required grouping and counting the occurrence of some values.
A dummy data set is

```
zipped=[(‘a’, ‘None’), (‘b’, ‘Premium’), (‘c’, ‘Basic’), (‘d’, ‘Basic’), (‘b’, ‘Premium’), (‘e’, ‘None’), (‘e’, ‘Basic’), (‘b’, ‘Premium’), (‘a’, ‘None’), (‘c’, ‘None’), (‘b’, ‘None’), (‘d’, ‘None’), (‘c’, ‘Basic’), (‘a’, ‘None’), (‘b’, ‘Basic’), (‘e’, ‘Basic’)]
```

So, I would like to find how many None, Basic and Premium are there in each of the a,b,c,d,e 
I need it to look like

```
{‘a’:[‘None’:3,‘Basic’:0,‘Premium’:0], ‘b’:[‘None’:1,‘Basic’:1,‘Premium’:3],…} .
```

I am also open to a better way of aggregation or data structure.
Here is what I tried to do

```
temp=Counter( x[1] for x in zipped  if x[0]=='b')
print(temp)
```

and I got

```
Counter({'Premium': 3, 'None': 1, 'Basic': 1})
```

Comment: Where did 'slashdot' and 'google' come from?

Comment: @Nathan my mistake slashdot ,google etc are the a,b,c ,etc

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `a`,`b` etc are your `slashdot`, `google`:

```
zipped=[('a', 'None'), ('b', 'Premium'), ('c', 'Basic'), ('d', 'Basic'), ('b', 'Premium'), 
        ('e', 'None'), ('e', 'Basic'), ('b', 'Premium'), ('a', 'None'), ('c', 'None'), 
        ('b', 'None'), ('d', 'None'), ('c', 'Basic'), ('a', 'None'), ('b', 'Basic'), 
        ('e', 'Basic')]


from collections import Counter

d = {}
for key,val in zipped:
    d.setdefault(key,[]).append(val) # create key with empty list (if needed) + append val.

# now they are ordered lists, overwrite with Counter of it:
for key in d:
    d[key] = Counter(d[key])

print(d)
```

Output:

```
 {'a': Counter({'None': 3}), 
  'b': Counter({'Premium': 3, 'None': 1, 'Basic': 1}), 
  'c': Counter({'Basic': 2, 'None': 1}), 
  'd': Counter({'Basic': 1, 'None': 1}), 
  'e': Counter({'Basic': 2, 'None': 1})}
```

Counter gives you `.most_common()` to get the lists you want:

```
for k in d:
    print(k,d[k].most_common())
```

Output:

```
a [('None', 3)]
b [('Premium', 3), ('None', 1), ('Basic', 1)]
c [('Basic', 2), ('None', 1)]
d [('Basic', 1), ('None', 1)]
e [('Basic', 2), ('None', 1)]
```

If you really need 0-counts, you can add them after the fact:

```
allVals = {v for _,v in zipped}   # get distinct values of zipped
for key in d:
    for v in allVals:
        d[key].update([v])        # add value once
        d[key].subtract([v])      # subtract value once
```

Bit cumbersome, but that way anyting will be present for all of them, with a 0 value if not present in `zipped`

```
for k in d:
    print(k,d[k].most_common())
```

Output:

```
a [('None', 3), ('Premium', 0), ('Basic', 0)]
b [('Premium', 3), ('None', 1), ('Basic', 1)]
c [('Basic', 2), ('None', 1), ('Premium', 0)]
d [('Basic', 1), ('None', 1), ('Premium', 0)]
e [('Basic', 2), ('None', 1), ('Premium', 0)]
```

Comment: thanks a lot . Some of the methods are new to me . A good opportunity to learn about them

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
data=[('a', 'None'), ('b', 'Premium'), ('c', 'Basic'), ('d', 'Basic'), ('b', 'Premium'),
        ('e', 'None'), ('e', 'Basic'), ('b', 'Premium'), ('a', 'None'), ('c', 'None'),
        ('b', 'None'), ('d', 'None'), ('c', 'Basic'), ('a', 'None'), ('b', 'Basic'),
        ('e', 'Basic')]


manual_dict={}

for i,j in enumerate(data):
    if j[0] not in manual_dict:
        manual_dict[j[0]]=[j[1]]
    else:
        manual_dict[j[0]].append(j[1])


final_dict={}

for ia,aj in manual_dict.items():
    final_dict[ia]={'None':aj.count('None'),'Basic':aj.count('Basic'),'Premium':aj.count('Premium')}

print(final_dict)
```

output:

```
{'c': {'Premium': 0, 'None': 1, 'Basic': 2}, 'a': {'Premium': 0, 'None': 3, 'Basic': 0}, 'd': {'Premium': 0, 'None': 1, 'Basic': 1}, 'b': {'Premium': 3, 'None': 1, 'Basic': 1}, 'e': {'Premium': 0, 'None': 1, 'Basic': 2}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another interesting implementation